# javascript - How to add array to array position

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, express

I'm trying to create a specific structure of data but I'm having troubles with that.

I want to do this:

- Parts

  - u_order
  - u_familia
  - u_part
  - u_type
  - articles (i want to add an array of articles here)

First, create the array parts:

```
parts.push(request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92'"));
```

Next I will iterate this array and for each part I get the `articles` of this part and I want to add them to parts array:

```
return Promise.all([Promise.all(parts)]).then(function(listOfResults)
    {
      var articles = [];
      for(var i=0; i<listOfResults[0][0].length; i++)
      {
        articles.push(request.query("SELECT ststamp, ref, design FROM st WHERE u_posic = '"+listOfResults[0][0][i].u_order+"'"));
      }

      Promise.all([Promise.all(articles)]).then(function(listOfArticles)
      {
        console.log("ARTICLES:");
        for(var j=0; j<listOfArticles[0][0].length; j++)
        {
          HERE I WANT TO ADD THE ARTICLE ARRAY TO PART
          I TRY USE SPLICE BUT DOESN'T WORK.
        }
      });

    }).catch(function(err)
    {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

How can I do that?

Thank you

Comment: show us how you were using splice, that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Parts `object` rather than a parts array.  Make an array of Parts objects containing the named keys including a key for articles:

```
var part = request.query("SELECT u_order, u_familia, u_part, u_type FROM u_part (nolock) where u_order <'92'");
var article = request.query("SELECT ststamp, ref, design FROM st WHERE u_posic = '"+listOfResults[0][0][i].u_order+"'");

parts.push({
  u_order: part[0],
  u_familia: part[1],
  u_part: part[2],
  u_type: part[3],
  articles: article
});
```